# TextView wraps short text without reason, while not wrapping longer text

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I'm creating an app and ran into a weird issue. My activity has this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:customfont="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_all"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="407dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_result"
            style="@style/font_Result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="216dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_unit"
            style="@style/font_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/id_result"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/id_result"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/id_image"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:textColor="@color/grey" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/id_unit"
            android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/id_result" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/id_image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/id_image"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/id_result" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my onCreate() I call the Views by their ID and set the texts and the drawables. Depending on a meassured result, there are two scenarios:

**1) Show the meassured result (let's say 42.9 GW/ms)**

- TextView `id_result`: '42.9'
- TextView `id_unit`: 'GW/ms'
- ImageView `id_image`: @drawable/image1_1
- ImageView `id_image2`: @drawable/image2_1

Everything is fine

**2) The result is too high**

- TextView `id_result`: 'HI'
- TextView `id_unit`: visibility GONE
- ImageView `id_image`: visibility GONE
- ImageView `id_image2`: visibility GONE

Now here is the problem. I expected the text 'HI' to be shown centered on screen. Instead, only "H" is shown. When I set `android:maxLines="2"`, it is revealed, that Android wraps the text after 'H'. 'I' sits on the second line. Why is this the case? '42.9' is longer and doesn't get wrapped.

Does anyone has a solution?